# Geolocator plugin can't give correct speed in Real Device

Tags: flutter, geolocator

I want to getting speed of vehicle using Geolocator package but it's not working correctly in Real Device. It's only working perfectly in AVD.

I have tested at 60-70 speed but package can't give above 30 speed...

It's my bug report link :

https://github.com/Baseflow/flutter-geolocator/issues/1390